# String replace equivalent for VB statement (";" & vbcrlf) in C#

Tags: c#, vbscript

Duplicating a function in C# from some old VB code to perform string manipulation on email text.  I am not sure if this will work in all cases...can anyone confirm my thoughts on the correct C# code to use?  Are these equivalent?

Original VB:

```
function FixText(Mail_Text)
   dim Clean_Text
   Clean_Text = Mail_Text
   Clean_Text = Replace(Clean_Text, "=" & vbcrlf, "")
   Clean_Text = Replace(Clean_Text, ";" & vblrcf, "")
   ` ... other stuff
   FixText = Clean_Text
End Function
```

New C#:

```
public String FixText(Mail_Text)
{
   String Clean_Text = Mail_Text;
   Clean_Text = Clean_Text.Replace("=" + System.Environment.NewLine, "");
   Clean_Text = Clean_Text.Replace(";" + System.Environment.NewLine, "");
   // ... other stuff
   return Clean_Text;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, they are not.  `vbcrlf` is a string constant equal to `"\r\n"` in C#.

`System.Environment.NewLine` is a property that returns `"\r\n"` on Windows systems, but returns `"\n"` on Unix-based systems (Linux and OS X) and more generally means "the line terminator for the current platform."  `vbcrlf` will *always* be the Windows CR+LF line terminator regardless of what platform the code is running on.

Which one you should use ultimately depends on how this text will be used, and this cannot be adequately inferred from other information in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  The code is only going to be used in a Windows system service that I am writing, so with that said, does it look correct for this purpose?

Comment: @user2696963 If the code will only ever run on Windows then yes, the two are effectively equivalent in functionality.  If there is any possibility that this will be ported to a \*nix system then it would be wise to determine which line ending is required.  (For example, HTTP *requires* CR+LF terminators, so `Environment.NewLine` would be *wrong* in that context.  It all depends on what kind of data you are building here.)

Comment: I completed my service and finished testing. The code works very nicely using the System.Environment.NewLine entry.  I also tested it with "=\r\n" and ";\r\n" which worked just as well.  Thanks for your input. +1

Answer (score 0):

You use C# [escape sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx):

```
Clean_Text = Clean_Text.Replace("=\r\n", "");
Clean_Text = Clean_Text.Replace(";\r\n", "");
```

- `\r` is the escape sequence for a carriage return,
- `\n` is the escape sequence for a new line.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that also.  Note also that the first line is written as "=" & vbcrlf and the second line is ";" & vblrcf.  So should the entries be Replace("=\r\n", "") and Replace(";\n\r", "")?

Comment: @CaryH `vblrcf` is not a [builtin constant](http://ss64.com/vb/syntax-constants.html). `vbcr`, `vblf`, and `vbcrlf` are all valid constants. I assumed that `vblrcf` was just a typo, but it's possble that that's a different variable defined elsewhere. Are you *sure* that the original code works as you posted it?

Comment: It was probably a typo in the old VB code, I never ran it, just dug it up from old reference files I have collected.